# Algebraic multiplicity of the Sturm-Liouville operator

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was wondering what does it mean for the eigenvalue of the operator to have the algebraic multiplicity 2? It is easy to understand with a matrix but no matrices here (at least finite). What is special about such eigenvalue?
Thank you very much.
Marina

Comment: There are several kinds of SL operators. How does yours look like?

Comment: It is L(f)(x)=f''(x)-q(x)*f(x) for non-negative q(x) with Dirichlet boundary conditions for eigenfunctions

Comment: Such an operator, considered in $L^2(a,b)$, is selfadjoint. So, if an eigenvalue has algebraic multiplicity two, the eigenspace is two-dimensional.

Comment: Thank you, I got that. But I am trying to prove that this is impossible.

Comment: Oh, your are right. I forgot. It is indeed impossible. The solution space of the differential equation $f'' + qf = \lambda f$ is two dimensional. So, if $T$ had an eigenvalue of multiplicity two, then every solution would be zero at $a$ and $b$. But there are also solutions $\varphi$ with $\varphi(a) = 1$ (and, e.g., $\varphi'(a) = 0$). Contradiction.

Comment: Hi Friedrich, could you be so kind to explain what do you mean " the solution space of the equation is two-dimensional"? and why then every solution have zeros on the ends? Thank you.

Comment: The solution space is the set consisting of all solutions to the differential equation. It is easily seen to be a vector space, and its dimension is two, since the ODE has order two. That's a known fact, which is not immediate, but still quite easily to show. And, well, you said you impose Dirichlet conditions in the domain of your operator. So, if $f$ is an eigenfunction of $T$ we must have $f(a) = f(b) = 0$. Now, if there are two linearly independent ones, say $f$ and $g$, then they span the solution space and for every solution $h = cf + dg$ we have $h(a) = cf(a) + dg(a) = 0$.

Comment: Thank you! That is amazingly clear.